# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 894: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, scikit-learn

I am using `scikit-learn` for a project. While performing feature extraction (working_with_text_data tutorial) I get UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte.

Using python 2.7.8 and have build `scikit-learn` using make.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(dataset.data)
print(X_train_counts.shape)
```

Kindly help on how to resolve?

Comment: can you show us the traceback?  and what's in `dataset.data`?  clearly one of the input data is a disallowed character.

Comment: You may want to try loading the data with the codec, `utf-8-sig`.  The file may have a utf-8 signature defined for the first three bytes, or just skip the first 3 bytes on read.

Comment: Check that the file you are loading is encoded in utf8. It might be another encoding.

Comment: As you rightly said it is problem with encoding. I directly used 'from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups' and it works. If i use 'from sklearn.datasets import load_files' to load files it doesn't work. I think if i change my file encoding it will work using load files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when using load_files function, encoding should be latin1

```
twenty_train = load_files('path/to/folder',encoding='latin1')
```

in sklearn/datasets/twenty_newscroups.py

```
function _download_20newsgroups
...
load_files(train_path, encoding='latin1')
```